# Execute a controller from view in ASP.NET MVC - Razor

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to print the name of the user who executes my web app. It is written in MVC-Razor.

From the initial View, I would to execute the controller below:

```
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Check()
    {
        var check = new CheckAD();
        var user = new User {Name = check.CheckSecurityWithAD()};
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.Name))
        {
            return View("Checked", user);
        }
        
        var errors = new ErrorsModel()
        {
            Messages = new List<string>(){"You don't have permission"}
        };
        
        return View("Error", errors);
    }
```

This controller returns another view if the user is correctly authenticated:

```
   @model UsersActivationWeb.Models.User

   @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Checked";
    }

   @{ <p> Logged come @Model.Name </p>};
```

How can I print the second view (I think it's a partial view) in the first one using the controller?

Thanks

Comment: In the first view, you need to use partial like `@html.Partial("ViewName")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds to me like you need an `Html.Action`.  This will run the controller code and display the view contents that are produced where you place the call.

Most likely you will need this overload, `Html.Action(string actionName, string controllerName)`.

Assuming the controller is called `CheckController`.  In your initial view call it like this

```
@Html.Action("Check","Check")
```

Since you don't want people navigating to the `Check` view you should give it a ChildActionOnly attribute so it looks like this

```
[Authorize]
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult Check()
{
   //rest of code
}
```

Finally you almost certainly don't want the layout contents to appear with the Checked view so change your Checked view to this

```
@model UsersActivationWeb.Models.User

@{
    Layout = null;
 }

@{ <p> Logged come @Model.Name </p>};
```

Since you are doing authorization logic in the `Check` action you might not need the `Authorize` attribute.  I say that because with it a user not logged in will not get the error or their name.  Maybe you want this though, I'd need to know more about your code to say for sure.

This way you will either get the name of the user or the errors as required.